# Remove an object from a Hashset in Java

Tags: java

I have a Hashset which holds 10 objects, how can I remove one of them? This is the code and now I need to create a method which removes one "slice of pizza"

```
private HashSet<Slice> pizza;

public Pizza(int slicesofPizza) {
   pizza = new HashSet<Slice>();

   for (int i = 0; i < slicesofPizza; i++) {        
       Slice slice = new Slice();
       pizza.add(slice);
   }
}
```

edit: What I am asking is if I have a method, how would I remove a singular slice or is this not possible :

public Slice removeSlice() {

```
    }
```

Comment: Javadoc to the rescue! https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html

Comment: It depends how you _identify_ a `Slice` object and the implementation of `hashcode()` & `equals()`. By the way, your code doesn't compile : what is a  `Penny` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
pizza.remove(slice)
```

will remove one "slice" from the hashset.

Comment: There's no guarantee about that, depending on how the `Slice` class is constructed. Unless you add that right after `add()`, but that's just not right.

Comment: No. This wouldn't remove one `slice`, it would remove that specific `slice` object from the HashSet. 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#remove(java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 0):

Using `HashSet` does not make that much sense, if you don't have a way of creating a `Slice` that is equal to some other `Slice` and don't store the slices in any other data structure.

In your case there is no parameter in the constructor that could help tell one `Slice` from the other, which means either all slices are equal or all slices are pairwise different. This either means the set contains at most one slice (use `clear()` in this case) or you cannot find a slice again without iterating the `Set`.

This makes `HashSet` just a rather inefficient `Collection` in this case.

However it could be done using an `Iterator`:

```
Iterator<Slice> iterator = pizza.iterator();
if (iterator.hasNext()) {
    iterator.next();
    iterator.remove();
}
```

Which will just remove the first slice returned by the `Iterator`, which could be an arbitrary one.

Comment: I assume it is better to break out of iterator loop after remove if only one match can be there. Otherwise it is better(or needed) to put them in another set and use removeAll() after iterations done. As I remeber concurrent modification will be thrown otherwise.

Comment: @Vadim it's not supposed to go inside any loop iterating over the set. The question IMHO asks about removing a slice after adding is complete and I do not use a loop either and even if I did: Using the same iterator should prevent the `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: You are removing only one next element regardless is it the same Slice or not. I do not think that is actual goal. But whatever... To remove particular slice one or another way there must be definition of Slice equality to the some criteria "to be removed"

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to override `equals(Object o)` method in `Slice` class, which will help while removing a `Slice` object from the `HashSet`.

While removing an element from `HashSet` it needs to compare passed object with the objects already present. You have to writein `equals(Object o)` method that on what terms you are considering two `Slice` object to be equal.

After that use this `pizza.remove(customSlice)`.

Answer (score 0):

The [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#remove-java.lang.Object-) interface has a remove method that will do the job.  Make sure that Slice implements hashcode and equals properly as well, since this can effect the behavior of the set methods.

Comment: Problem is that the user apparently doesn't have a particular slice to `remove` on.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to override equals method in your Slice class and in all classes which extends Penny class.
   It is needed to make pizza.remove method works.
   as example one Slice equals another if their types, sizes and prices equal to each other. (or any other attributes)
2. Then you can use

   ```
   Slice sliceToRemove = new Slice(type,size,price);
   pizza.remove(sliceToRemove);
   ```

it will remove slice from Set if there is a slice with the same type,size and price.

Anyway you have to have attributes which identify a slice in the Set.

Without overriding equals you have to iterate through the Set, check those attributes and then remove if they match.